# Sitecore10 .Net Core Getting Started Template Architecture for Creating Action Methods

Tags: authentication, login

I am quite new to Sitecore 10, .Net Core , Docker, so asking this silly question :)

I have followed the Sitecore 10 .Net core getting started template and able to create base setup. Now I understand that in container environment

1. we have a platform project which runs on .Net framework 4.8 and should contain all Sitecore related code (Pipeline, Content Resolver etc.)
2. A rendering host which is build on .net core and should have all front end logic

Now, I want to build a simple login flow with Register, Login, Edit profile page, so as part of authentication we should be having submit action/Pipeline and with in these submit-action/pipeline we need to use Sitecore DLL for authentication. Hence, where should I be writing the pipeline/submit-action code?

1. Will it be in Rendering host .net core project ? But it give warning as sitecore dll are in .net framework 4.8
2. Or do I need to create APIs in Platform project and call it from Rendering host project?

The Getting started template only gives demo how we can fetch and show data from sitecore but what about submitting data from rendering host?
I have also explore the helix example for .net core but there as well we only have example how the content can be fetch and show.

Any Idea?

Comment: The Layout Service will respect any logged in users and Sitecore Security. User management should be made in .Net Core project that calls Sitecore Authentication APIS  to RESTfully log into Sitecore and set the .ASPXAUTH cookie: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html. If these do not cover all your needs, you can build new ones in the Platform projects. So, option 2.